# Network traffic Encryption without Certificates

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm tasked with encryption of the network communication of our program and I've been thrown a wrench. I was going to use [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) but my CTO would like to stay away from managing certificates. So I was wondering is there any other Stream that will encrypt data, or a way to dynamically generate certificates?

Comment: I'd advice to either to stick with default implementation OR find someone who either expert in the security or have authority to sign any decisions. While there is "no bad PR" having your name associated with serious security vulnerabilities may not be the best on the resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encrypt your data using a standard encryption algoithm (RSA, AES, PGP, etc.) as long as you control both endpoints. If not, you will need to use something like certificates since clients won't be able to otherwise decrypt. I'm not sure why your CTO would avoid certs, but nonetheless...

See this article for a good start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ss79b2x.aspx

Also note that WCF supports MANY means of communication encryption, many of which do not require certs.

[WCF netTCPBinding - Is transport encryption enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99001/wcf-nettcpbinding-is-transport-encryption-enough)

Note finally that you cannot encrypt the message headers if you don't talk directly to the other party (ie: if there's anyone in the middle), since the middle part won't be able to decipher/route your message.